# vue property as prop name without value

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-tooltip

I want to pass a property that doesn't have any value - only name. I want the name to be dynamic according the prop.

I want to create a component of tool-tip that get the tool-tip side -> top left right or bottom. in v-tooltip there isn't property *side*, all side is another property without value. I want it to change according the prop (side is a variable - a prop of my component).

```
<template>
  <v-tooltip side>            
    <template slot="activator">
      <slot slot="activator"></slot>
    </template>   
    <span>{{text}}</span>      
  </v-tooltip>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      text: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      side: {
        default: 'top',
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

I can't find a way to use prop as the name of the property

Answer (score 4):

There are two things that you need to realise. In Vue, calling a component with `<my-component has-this-prop />` it the same as calling a component with `<my-component :has-this-prop="true" />`. The boolean basically toggles the prop.

You can also dynamically change which props are bound to a component by using the `v-bind` syntax without a prop name, as outlined [in the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-the-Properties-of-an-Object).

This means that if you have a prop called `side` in your parent component that always contains the correct side, you can create a computed property that contains all the props you want to pass, then use `v-bind` on your `v-tooltip` to pass the props:

```
<template>
  <v-tooltip v-bind="tooltipProps">
    <!-- Something -->
  </v-tooltip>
</template>

<script>
const validSides = [
  'top',
  'top left',
  'top center',
  'top right',
  // you get the idea
];

export default {
  props: {
    side: {
      type: String,
      default: 'top',
      validator(prop) {
        return validSides.contains(prop);
      }
    }
  },

  computed: {
    tooltipProps() {
      if (!validSides.contains(this.side)) {
        return {};
      }

      const propsNames = this.side.split(' ');
      const props = {};
      for (const propName of propsNames) {
        props[propName] = true;
      }

      return props;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```